# LibGDX splicing up texture file

Tags: libgdx, textures

I have an image, which consists of blocks (32*32) and there is 1 row and 4 columns. How can I do, that when I load a texture, I only load one block and not all 4 of them?

Comment: Do you want to actually load in the memory only this specific block ,or to use only this specific block as a texture in a sprite?

Comment: As a texture for rendering with sprite batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1)**

```
    Texture texture=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ui/logo2.png"));
    Sprite sprite=new Sprite(texture);
    sprite.setRegion(0, 0, 1f/4f, 1);//this loads the first block
    sprite.setRegion(1f/4f, 0, 1f/4f+1f/4f, 1);//this loads the second block
    sprite.setRegion((1f/4f)*2, 0, 1f/4f+(1f/4f)*2, 1);//this loads the third block
    //on render
    sprite.draw(theSpriteBatch);
```

**Method 2)**

```
    Texture texture=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ui/logo2.png"));
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(texture, 32, 32);
    Sprite sprite=new Sprite(tmp[0][0]);//first
    Sprite sprite=new Sprite(tmp[0][1]);//second
    Sprite sprite=new Sprite(tmp[0][2]);//third
    //on render
    sprite.draw(yourSpriteBatch);
```